# What do Hindu scriptures say about river worship?

Tags: scripture, belief, rivers

I wish to know about river worship in Hinduism.

What do Hindu scriptures really say about river worship?

Comment: Rivers like Ganga,Yamuna etc are worshiped.I think there are many examples from scriptures depicting the same.Several stotrams are dedicated towards them.Ex-http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Valmiki_Krutha_Gangashtakam. Also in ritualistic Puja rivers like Ganga Yamuna Sarswati are  worshiped during Varuna puja.

Comment: Another nice stotram u can read here:http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Dasa_hara_Ganga_sthothram

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Devi Bhagavata Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/devibhagvatpurana70.html) and the [Brahma Vaivarta Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/brahma%20vaivartha/bookview.php?chapnum=13)  mention the process of worshiping Ganga.In the context of Bhagiratha's penance to bring the holy river on earth.

> It was the Grandson of Asamanja and the son of Ansuman- the
> illustrious Bhagiratha, who made persistent efforts to meditate Devi
> Ganga, Vishnu and  Sankara and finally succeeded in bringing the Holy
> River from Vishnu’s feet to Sankara’s head and down to Bhu Loka and
> purified the ashes of the thousand Sagara ‘Putras’(Sons) and relieved
> their tormented souls to Heavens.The Holy River flowing as a ‘Jeeva
> Nadi’ till date across the entire ‘Aryavarta’ from Gangotri to the Bay
> of Bengal, is a unique land mark of Bharata Varsha, blessing lakhs of
> devotees for bathing and purifying their sins at several points
> dotting from Haridvar, Varanasi, Prayaga and Patna. Even a mere
> bathing in the River washes off several sins, and performing it with a
> ‘Sankalpa’or resolve especially on a day when Sun passes from one
> Zodiac Sign to another bestows significance thrice over.
>
> **Maharshi Narayana explained to Narada the mehodology of Worship to
> Ganga in brief:** one should have a hearty bath in Ganga, don clean
> clothes, be seated on the banks of the River to perform the daily
> Sandhyavandana first and invoke the blessings the Six Devatas
> viz.Ganesha, Sun, Agni, Vishnu, Siva and Sivani. Do worship Ganesha to
> remove the obstacles, Surya Deva for good health, Agni Deva for
> purification, Vishnu for wealth and power, Siva for knowledge and
> Sivani for salvation. Then, imagine a mental image of  Ganga Devi in
> fulfledged form with ‘Ashta Hasta’ ( Eight hands) fully decorated with
> a smiling face, ornaments, flower garlands, and armoury and above all
> an ‘Abhaya Mudra’ or a protective posture of two hands- one to provide
> security and another for giving away boons. The ‘Dhyanam’ or
> meditation is to be highly concentrated and serious without mind
> wavering on any other object or thought, excepting the Image of Ganga,
> in physical form to facilitate ‘dhyana’ or meditation. Then perform
> the Shodadasa Sevas viz. ‘Asana’, Padya’, ‘Arghya’, ‘Snana’,
> ‘Anulepaya ( Ointment), ‘Dhoopa’( Inscence), ‘Dipa’( Light)’,
> ‘Naivedya’ ( Offer of Food Items), ‘Tamboola’ ( betel leaves and
> nuts), ‘Paniya’ (cool water), ‘Vastra’ ( clothing), ‘Abharana’(
> Ornaments), ‘Pushpa’ (flowers), ‘Gandha’( Sandal Paste), ‘Achamaniya’
> (water for sipping) and ‘Arati’ ( Camphor lighting). Thereafter, the
> devotee should render  ‘Stotras’ ( Hymns) to say that in Vaikuntha the
> River is six lakh yojanas wide and four times that in length; in
> Brahma Loka, thirty lakh yojanas in width and five times that in
> length; in Dhruva Loka it is one lakh yojanas in width and seven times
> as long and so on.

The quotes are taken from the 1st link given above.