# What are the ways to worship the water in Hinduism?

Tags: gods

What are the ways to worship the water in Hinduism?

Is there a way to slaughter chicken or other animals to the water and worship it by giving it blood?

Comment: Worshipping holy rivers like Ganga, Narmada etc. is quite common among Hindus. See [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14949/what-do-hindu-scriptures-say-about-river-worship) post for example. Worshipping simply water is not that common. BTW the deity which presides over water is Varuna.